# 'fadeIn' doesn't work when first time click on button [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, html

When I first time click on button it show just loader, if I use fadeOut I can click just one time after that fade not working... Here is my code:

```
if(data == 'success'){
 $('#msg').addClass('alert alert-success').fadeIn(3000,function(){
 $(this).hide(); 
                    });
  $('#msg').text('Successfully logged in.....  Redirecting....');
}
```

If block above is called on button click.
Here is HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;" id="message">
  <span class="" id="msg" ></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a js fiddle (jsfiddle.net) if you can as this isn't the complete source.

Comment: I have solution anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sove my problem, I put fadeOut inside fadeIn function:

```
if(data == 'success'){
$('#msg').addClass('alert alert-success').fadeIn(2000,function(){
$('#msg').fadeOut(3000,function(){
   $('#msg').removeClass('alert alert-success');
});
 });

$('#msg').text('Successfully logged in.....  Redirecting....');
 }
```